# How to get another app's context in android?

Tags: java, android, android-context

Is it possible to get another application's context if I have the **Package-Name**? I need to get application's context anyhow... Please answer if any one know..

Comment: You can't.  A Context is a variable of a running application.  These are sandboxed from each other.  There may be another way to do what you really want to, but you can't get the Context.

Comment: @GabeSechan see, what official android is saying... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.  You can get limited access to its resources that way.  But what's returned is not the same as the application context or an activity context for a running instance of the application.

Comment: Actually, I want to get cacheDir of an app through this way. So I tried if this is possible

Comment: You might be able to get the directory name, but no read or write access to it

Comment: Yeah, you are right. That's a big bug. Android may allow me to get that directory but as far as I think, android won't allow me to edit...